# sublime Each filetype has a unique icon and preferably a unique colorcode

Tags: sublimetext2

I am trying to customize my sublime text editor 2, however, I want make for each file type a unique icon

for example

```
   index.php { unique icon for .php  }
   app.html  { unique icon for .html }
   style.css { unique icon for .css  }
```

however I after searching I found [this article](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/19274-theming-of-the-sidebar/#comment_110552)

and the [plugin on the git hub](https://github.com/namsral/Coder-Icons).

however the guy who create this plugin, he did't explain enough where this code should go in

order to the plugin works, I have tried and paste it in different places but no luck. it dose not work. 
dose anybody familiar with this code where should I paste it ...?
dose anybody know any good articles or any kind of resource that can guide through in order to get this work ... ?

```
{
       "class": "sidebar_items",
       "content_padding": [0, 0, 0, 20],
       "content_background_width": [16],
       "content_background_height": [16],
       content_background_image": 
       {

              "filetype:css": "Packages/Theme - Default/stylesheet.png",
              "filetype:js": "Packages/Theme - Default/javascript.png",
              "filetype:json": "Packages/Theme - Default/json.png"
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The post you linked to was a link to a Sublime Theme so you'd install it like any other package.

1. Unzip the files
2. Find your Packages directory using the menu item Preferences -> Browse Packages...
3. Copy the folder into your Sublime Text Packages directory

However, you want the folders on the sidebar and the Soda theme so I'd recommend you visit the [GitHub page](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme) for this project as the author has put [instructions](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme#installation) on how to go about installing the theme and configuring the folder icons. The theme supports both Sublime Text 2 and 3.

As for the custom icons that you requested, you may have to contact the developer and request that as a feature or you could dive into the theme yourself and implement the feature.